# How to make parameters Optional in node JS rest API

Tags: node.js, rest, node-request

We need to Expose REST endpoint. There are three parameters, how to make those optional.
Requirement is it should work with any one of those parameters.

e.g. `http://server:port/v1/api/test-api/userId/UnameName/userEmail`

```
app.get('v1/api/test-api/:userId/:userName/:userEmail', function(req, res){

});
```

When we call by passing all three parameters it works fine. But we want to make it work by passing only userId or any of these three parameters. When we pass less parameters its giving error `Cannot GET /v1/api/test-api/test5/123`

How to make parameters optional while exposing endpoint?

Comment: What is the resource this API is accessing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to structure the route like this:

```
app.get('path/:required/:optional?*, ...)
```

Answer (score 8):

A better solution would be to use GET parameters, e.g. a call to

```
http://server:port/v1/api/test-api?userId=123&userName=SomeKittens&userEmail=kittens%40example.com
```

You can then define your routes like:

```
app.get('v1/api/test-api', function(req, res){
  var userName = req.query.userName;
  var userEmail = req.query.userEmail;
  var userId = req.query.userId;

  // Do stuff
});
```

Don't forget to include [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131469/1216976))

Answer (score 1):

Trying to add more clarity to @thebiglebowsy's answer, you could use:

**required** -> required1/required2/...

**optional** -> ?optional/?optional2/..

But, my advice is to generate a route per every posibility:

`v1/api/test-api/:userId/`

`v1/api/test-api/:userId/:userName`

`v1/api/test-api/:userId/:userName/:userEmail`

I had several issues using with optional routes

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way, you can check whether what you have received in your input request parameters and put validations or capture values accordingly..

```
app.post('/v1/api/test-api', function(req, res) {
    var parameters = [];
    if(req.body.userName !== undefined) {
         //DO SOMEHTING
         parameters.push({username: req.body.userName});
    }
    if(req.body.userId !== undefined) {
        //DO SOMEHTING

       parameters.push({userId: req.body.userId});
   }
   if(req.body.userEmail !== undefined) {
      //DO SOMEHTING
      parameters.push({userEmail: req.body.userEmail});
   }

   res.json({receivedParameters: parameters});

});
```